# Swift 3.0 CoreData create multi context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

Previously in the application i was using multi context approach to use background context to do manipulation with data in the background thread. It was done like this.

```
 // backgroundContext in the background thred
    lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        let coordinator = self.store.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var backgroundContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return backgroundContext
    }()
```

And it was used like this:

```
self.coreDataManager.saveContext(self.coreDataManager.backgroundContext!)
```

How with new CoreData update we should handle multiple CoreData contexts? Because now with `NSPersistentContainer` it should be handled a bit in another way.

Comment: Have you tried the `newBackgroundContext()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Apple's own documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/ReleaseNotes.html), and the [What's new in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/242/) talk, this is the recommended way to do it:

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer.persistentContainerWithName("myApp")
container.performBackgroundTask() { (moc) in
    // use moc to do asynchronous work
}
```

By default, the NSPersistentContainer provides a context for UI related tasks, `ViewContext`, and the ability to create as many background contexts you may need, by doing:

`let moc = container.newBackgroundContext`

Notice though, that int the talk they recommend the use of `performBackgroundTask()` instead of creating your own background context. This is because the said method does some optimizations that wouldn't take place if you use the context by yourself.